# connect grails 3 app on heroku with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails, heroku

I have deployed grails 3 app on heroku and setup a  database addon postgresql. However I don't know the process to connect them. please show me the stepwise process to do so

Comment: What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Comment: i did the required congifs to the application.yml file but it never worked so i connected it  to external mysql database(outside heroku) .and it worked